# Eager loading of reverse related elements?

Tags: relations, elementcriteriamodel, eager-loading

Is it possible to load reverse related elements? I mean if the elements I’m querying are the target elements?

Example:

I’m setting up a criteria model to get some categories and I also want to load the entries related to each category. I’m using a Categories field, so my categories are the target elements of those relations.

```
{% for category in craft.categories.group('news').all() %}
    {% set query = craft.entries.relatedTo({
        targetElement: category,
        field: 'myCategoriesField',
    }) %}

    {# Oh no, a N+1 query problem... #}
    {% set entries = query.all() %}
{% endfor %}
```

I could probably do it the other way around, query for the entries and eager load the categories. Then use the `group` filter to order everything by category. But that approach is awkward and has limitations, e.g. doesn’t play well with pagination.

Comment: Did anything ever come of this?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't eager loading the wrong idea here, since categories do not have a property anyway, which automatically points to entries assign to this category?

Let's take 2 samples:

Sample #1: behavior like lazy loading (one entry query per category)

```
{% for category in categories %}
{% set entries = craft.entries...relatedTo(category)
{% endfor %}
```

Sample #2: behavior like eager loading (one entry query for all categories)

```
{% set entries = craft.entries...relatedTo(categories)
```

Now the only trick is to sort the entries in a way that they are easy accessible from each category in the `{% for category in categories %}` loop.

Or should't Craft automatically cache the loaded categories and therefor make accessing them from the entry fast after having executed the Sample #2 query?

What I mean is that it would not become faster, only more comfortable if this eager loading was possible.

Only ideas...

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do the missing step, get each group of entries related to every category? It’s not really possible without further queries, is it? I mean, you got the right set of entries there, but that doesn’t help much if we loose the relations.

Comment: What do you mean by “categories do not have a property”? The entry to categories relationship was just picked because I though it would illustrate the reverse-relation problem clearly, as categories are usually the target elements. But the issue does actually apply to all element relationships.

Comment: ad 1: I will try, give me some time
ad 2: you are right, I just meant that it's a question of comfort and not a question of amount of queries. Coming from the src side of a relation always gives you the property containing the relation, but never from the target side.